# How to know that an automated regsvr32 doesn't work

Tags: c#, dll, process, regsvr32, processstartinfo

Following is my code:

```
private static bool Register(string fullFileName, string username, SecureString password)
    {
        var isRegistered = false;

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            var startInfo = process.StartInfo;

            startInfo.FileName = "regsvr32.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/s {0}", fullFileName);
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            startInfo.UserName = username;
            startInfo.Password = password;

            try
            {
                isRegistered = process.Start();                    
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message );
            }
        }

        return isRegistered;
    }
}
```

1. If the username and passord are wrong for example, it will enter the catch part and I can return false - FINE
2. If I am commenting out the following:

   ```
   startInfo.Verb = "runas";
   startInfo.UserName = username;
   startInfo.Password = password;
   ```

then it will not work since it need to be registered as admin. but the isRegistered will be set to true.

How can I know that it doesn't work?

Note: I am running it in silence mode so the user can't see the prompt. The error prompt is displayed when working in non-silent mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `process.WaitForExit()`, you should check the process's exit code.

```
Process.ExitCode
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It is `0` if all succeeded. Non-zero if failed.